# Angular 2 reverse countdown timer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm looking for a reverse countdown timer for an Angular project. Something like this: https://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/

I tried all the observable and rxjs timer but nothing seems to satisfy the need of my project. Can someone help me with a reverse countdown timer or modify the above links code to be used in an Angular project?

Comment: RxJS doesn't have anything like that by default ... you can either try to find some npm library or write it yourself, it's fairly simple.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović, you can check a FAIRLY SIMPLE AND EASY code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class CountDown {

    // Hardcoded date
    private endDate: Date = new Date(2018, 9, 22);

    private diff: number;
    private countDownResult: number;
    private days: number;
    private hours: number;
    private minutes: number;
    private seconds: number;

    constructor() {

        Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
                this.diff = Math.floor((this.endDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
            }).subscribe((x) => {           
                this.days = this.getDays(this.diff);
                this.hours = this.getHours(this.diff);
                this.minutes = this.getMinutes(this.diff);
                this.seconds = this.getSeconds(this.diff);
            });
    }

    getDays(t){
        var days;
        days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
        return days;
    }

    getHours(t){
        var days, hours;
        days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
        t -= days * 86400;
        hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
        return hours;
    }

    getMinutes(t){
        var days, hours, minutes;
        days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
        t -= days * 86400;
        hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
        t -= hours * 3600;
        minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
        return minutes;
    }

    getSeconds(t){
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
        days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
        t -= days * 86400;
        hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
        t -= hours * 3600;
        minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
        t -= minutes * 60;
        seconds = t % 60;
        return seconds;
    }
```